# ArrayList.indexOf versus sequential searching of an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist

Does the JVM run through an *array* of Objects faster than an *ArrayList* of Objects?

To elaborate, say I have two variables

```
Object theObject = someObject; 
Object[] objArr;
ArrayList objArrList;
```

Assuming both objArr and objArrList have the same elements, will iterating over the elements of `objArray` until I find the element of interest take the same amount of time as using `objArrList.indexOf(...)`

I.e. is this:

```
int length = objArray.length;
for(int i=0; i<length; i++){ 
   if(objArray[i].equals(someObject)){
      idx = i; break;
   }
}
```

basically the same as

`objArrList.indexOf(theObject);`

*or* do ArrayLists (and Lists in general) have an optimized search that is better than the simple -go-through-each-element-in-sequence method?

Thanks!

Comment: `Arraylist` imposes no ordering (and does not store elements in a hashtable) so it almost certainly does a naive linear search for `indexOf`. Measure and see if the speeds are roughly similar! (Or do a search for the `ArrayList` source.)

Comment: Also note that ArrayList is actually just a wrapper on an Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implemntation of `ArrayList.indexOf(Object o)` is copied below

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It does the same exact thing that you did on an array. (with some different checks for null).

So the JVM will run through both in the same amount of time.